# Sort by column from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select, sql-order-by

I need a list over all Books in my db. 
The list should contain:

Name of the Publisher , Book Title , year of publication for all books.

The list must be sorted alphabetically in order of publisher and then title.

**I am not able to sort the list for BOTH condition, just for one.**

Here the tables:

Publishers table

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Publishers`;")
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE `Publishers` (
  `PublisherID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `City` TEXT NULL,
  `Country` TEXT NULL
);
```

Books table

```
   cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Books`;")
   cursor.execute('''
   CREATE TABLE `Books` (
  `BookID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `Title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ISBN` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ISBN13` TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (length(ISBN13)=13), 
  `PublisherID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Year_Published` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Price` DOUBLE NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`PublisherID`) REFERENCES Publishers(PublisherID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
''')
```

I was able to write this but not to sort it for BOTH conditions

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute('''SELECT Publishers.name,title,Year_Published 
                            FROM books
                            INNER JOIN publishers on publishers.PublisherID = books.PublisherID
                            ORDER BY
                            title ASC, name.publisher ASC;'''):
                          print(row)
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, please?

Comment: Sorry did not see i havent posted it

Comment: Publishers.name instead of name.publisher in the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a join:

```
select p.name, b.title, b.year_published
from books b
inner join publishers p on p.publisherID = b.publisherID
order by p.name, b.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I had written a wrong conditions. Answer seems to be the following thanks to all!1

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute('''SELECT Publishers.name,title,Year_Published 
                            FROM books
                            INNER JOIN publishers on publishers.PublisherID = books.PublisherID
                            ORDER BY
                            publishers.name ASC, books.title ASC;'''):

                          print(row)
cursor.close()
```